# What's the meaning of 'more of them'?

Tags: pronouns

> Regardless of whether the people existing after agriculture were happier, healthier, or neither, it is undeniable that there were more of **them**.

What is them here? Is it 'the people' or 'more than the things like to be happy and healthy?

Comment: 'Them' is a pronoun, and must refer to a plural noun (to two or more people or things previously mentioned or easily identified), and the only preceding noun is 'people'.

Comment: I agree with you that the only preceding noun in the form of plural is the 'people'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Them' is a pronoun, and must refer to a plural noun (to two or more people or things previously mentioned or easily identified), and the only preceding noun is 'people'.

> them   pronoun
>
> used as the object of a verb or preposition to refer to two or more
> people or things previously mentioned or easily identified.
>
> *"I bathed the kids and read them stories"*

(Oxford Languages via Google)